# Чем плохи вложенные условия?

Tags: python, java, if

Я часто слышу, что вложенные условия не грамоты, что есть более лучший способ реализации. Разве это плохо?;

Почему вложенные if считают неграмотный кодом?;

Как правильно реализовывать условия?;

Comment: проблема "плохого" кода всегда одна - читаемость. лучше - ооп, в частности полиморфизм

Comment: Количество ветвлений (условных операторов) определяет сложность программы, чем больше таких операторов, тем сложнее понять программу.  Для уменьшения сложности применяют различные способы декомпозиции / преобразования логических выражений

Answer (score 4):

Зачастую вложенные условия понижают читабельность кода. Для примера возьмем функцию, создающую пользователя. Перед созданием нам нужно проверить имя пользователя и его пароль:

```py
USERNAMES = {'peter', '123', 'progamer'}


def create_new_user(username, password):
    global USERNAMES
    USERNAMES.add(username)


def register_user():
    username = input()
    password = input()

    if len(username) <= 20:
        if len(username) > 3:
            if username in USERNAMES:
                print("User with this username already exists")
            else:
                if len(password) > 3:
                    create_new_user(username, password)
                    print("New user is created")
                else:
                    print("The password is too short")
        else:
            print("Username is too short")
    else:
        print("Username is too long")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register_user()
```

Функция `register_user()` выполняет свою задачу, но его тяжело отнести к категории читаемых - несколько вложенных условий, каждрое из которых отвечает за какую-то проверку. Если потребуется добавить новые проверки, то придется каждый раз вчитываться во вложенные условия и стараться не задеть уже существующие условия и их функционал.

У этой проблемы есть два (не взаимоисключающих) решения.

### Разворачивание

Если внутри условий есть места, где функция "досрочно" завершает выполнение, то можно попробовать "развернуть" эти условия. Такое условие:

```py
if len(password) > 3:
    create_new_user(username, password)
    print("New user is created")
else:
    print("The password is too short")
```

Можно развернуть так:

```py
if len(password) <+ 3:
    print("The password is too short")
    return
else:
    create_new_user(username, password)
    print("New user is created")
```

И так как при выполнении условия мы покидаем фунцию, мы можем убрать `else` (тем самым уменьшая вложенность):

```py
if len(password) <+ 3:
    print("The password is too short")
    return
create_new_user(username, password)
print("New user is created")
```

Применив эту технику несколько раз, в конце получим изначальную функцию `register_user()` в таком виде:

```py
def register_user():
    username = input()
    password = input()

    if len(username) > 20:
        print("Username is too long")
        return

    if len(username) <= 3:
        print("Username is too short")
        return

    if username in USERNAMES:
        print("User with this username already exists")
        return

    if len(password) <= 3:
        print("The password is too short")
        return

    create_new_user(username, password)
    print("New user is created")
```

В таком виде код довольно линеен, добавление новых проверок (и действий в случае их нарушения) стало проще.

### Вынесение

Еще один способ "облегчения" условий - вынесение их в отдельные функции. Пример:

```py
def is_username_valid(username):
    if len(username) > 20:
        print("Username is too long")
        return False

    if len(username) <= 3:
        print("Username is too short")
        return False

    if username in USERNAMES:
        print("User with this username already exists")
        return False

    return True


def is_password_valid(password):
    if len(password) <= 3:
        print("The password is too short")
        return False
    return True


def register_user():
    username = input()
    password = input()

    if not is_username_valid(username):
        return

    if not is_password_valid(password):
        return

    create_new_user(username, password)
    print("New user is created")
```

Здесь проверки вынесены в отдельные функции, что повысило читаемость - теперь по одним лишь названиям вызываемых функций точно видно, что `register_user()` проверяет имя пользователя и пароль, и если они валидны, создает пользователя.

P.S. Для практики и лучшего понимания можно вернуться к своему старому коду и попробовать повысить его читаемость этими способами.